# mail failed; [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:645)

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, ssl, smtplib

This is a question about sending an email through an authenticated SMTP (not gmail). The below script was put together through various questions and answers on this site but I get an error that has no "googlable" candidates for this particular combination of tools. I'm working in Python 3.5.1 and it produces this error:

> mail failed; [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:645)

Is this client side error or server? Am I missing some certificates I'm not aware of? AFAIK server supports SSL authentication. Any thoughts and nudges in the right direction will be appreciated.

```
import sys
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL as SMTP
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# credentials masked, obviously
SMTPserver = 'myserver'
sender = 'mymail'
destination = ['recipient']

USERNAME = "myusername"
PASSWORD = "mypass"

# typical values for text_subtype are plain, html, xml
text_subtype = 'plain'

content = """\
Test message
"""

subject = "Sent from Python"

try:
    msg = MIMEText(content, text_subtype)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    conn = SMTP(host=SMTPserver, port=465)
    conn.set_debuglevel(False)
    conn.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

    try:
        conn.sendmail(sender, destination, msg.as_string())
    finally:
        conn.quit()

except Exception as exc:
    sys.exit("mail failed; %s" % str(exc))
```

Comment: I suspect your server isn't using SSL/TLS. Can you try to connect to it from the command line, e.g. with: `openssl s_client -connect myserver:465`? If the server is working properly it should negotiate the SSL connection and display an SMTP banner.

Comment: I had a similar error when using SMTP SSL from Flask-Mail. Using TLS it worked OK.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to both commentators under my question. After navigating around SSL by setting

```
from smtplib import SMTP as SMTP
```

and enabling TLS once the STMP object is created (forgive me if I'm not using the correct terminology)

```
conn = SMTP(host=SMTPserver, port=587)  # object created
conn.ehlo() 
conn.starttls()  # enable TLS
conn.ehlo()
```

I was able to send e-mail.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I just changed from:

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

To:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Seems like yours was for a Django use-case. Correct?

Comment: Yes, it is for a Django use case

Comment: This is not useful for the question, because EMAIL_USE_SSL does not appear in the example code.

Comment: vy32 this might be the missing configuration that needs to be added to solve the issue, and that was exactly what I had to add when I had the same issue.

Comment: For anyone using Flask-Mail or Flask-Security, a variation of this answer fixes your SSL problem - `MAIL_USE_TLS = True` - The Flask-Security docs say to use MAIL_USE_SSL but you want TLS instead.

Comment: i change it to email_use_tls true but still i am getting the same error